# Update database after paypal payment successful

Tags: paypal

i want get transaction id from `paypal` after customer already paid by `paypal` account to update my database Please Help.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to get the transaction ID from your PayPal account just login into your PayPal account and go to the "Transaction History", now next to each transaction you can click on details and you can see the transaction ID. If you mean to get this detail through customized code please explain in details your request, Thanks, Andre.

Comment: i want redirect to my website after payment success and insert transaction id to database

Comment: Usually this operation, writing into your database, is handled by your eCommerce solution used. Once a buyer do a payment PayPal process the payment and notify your eCommerce backoffice and the transaction ID is recorded in your database. You can get the transaction ID from PayPal IPN.

Answer (score 0):

IPN is a message service that notifies you of events related to PayPal transactions. You can use it to automate your back-office and administrative functions and get information on transactions.
In order to use this feature you need first to activate it on your account. 
1) Access your PayPal account (www.paypal.com)
2) Click on Profile
3) Click on Instant Payment Notification Preferences
**Please note that if you have new Layout on your PayPal account you need to click on My selling preferences and then on Update just beside Instant payments notifications
4) Click on Choose IPN Settings
5) Add a Notification URL (you must have a listener ready, examples below)
6) Make sure to check IPN messages on Receive IPN messages (Enabled)
7) Click on Save

Make sure also to check every value of the variable notify_url (if you use WPS) in every PayPal button or PAYMENTREQUEST_n_NOTIFYURL (if you use Express Checkout). Their value can overwrite the value you wrote on your PayPal profile for Notification URL.

Please find below some useful links:

Instant Payment Notification:

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNIntro/

Setting up IPN:

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNSetup/